# Javascript error while trying to $.get

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is the error I get in chrome developers console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Comment> has no method 'querySelectorAll' tviggr.content.dev.js:3094
that.proccessNode tviggr.content.dev.js:3094
(anonymous function) tviggr.content.dev.js:3212
p.event.dispatch tviggr.content.dev.js:2
g.handle.h tviggr.content.dev.js:2
(anonymous function) jquery.js:6163
x.extend.access jquery.js:861
x.fn.extend.html jquery.js:6138
(anonymous function) pages.js:41
c jquery.js:3048
p.fireWith jquery.js:3160
k jquery.js:8235
r
```

And that's the part of pages.js code where the problem is.

```
function nHome(){
    if(currentSiteUrl!="pages/home.php" && switchProcess==false){
        //Translation and variables stuff.
        switchProcess = true;
        $('#mainContent').fadeTo(200,0.0001);
        //Page loading stuff.
        setTimeout(function(){$.when($.ajax(
            {
                url:"pages/home.php",
                cache:false,
                success: function(pagesData)
                {
                    content = pagesData;
                    $('title').html('Home - kamillozz7k');
                    //Setting var for current site
                    currentSiteUrl = 'pages/home.php';
                }
            })).done(function(){
                $('#mainContent').html(content);
                $('#mainContent').fadeTo(500,1);
                setTimeout(function(){switchProcess = false;},300);
            });
                             },200);
    }
}
```

I was looking for the answear overhere but I haven't found it so that's why I'm posting it.

Comment: What does the HTML for #mainContent look like?

Comment: The error looks like it's coming from the tviggr extension. What happens if you disable it?

Comment: @jfriend00 it looks like that
<div id="mainContent">
</br><center><img src="static/images/loading.gif" /></center></br>
</div>

Comment: @Barmar Nothing happends, but what I forget to tell you is that I've got 4 functions like that and only when i run this one it show the error.

Comment: Which line is line 41 of pages.js? The error is happening in a `.html()` call, but is it `$('title').html()` or `$('#mainContent').html()`?

Comment: fun fact: title talks about `$.get`, code doesn't use `.get` anywhere

Comment: It's also confusing to use both the `success:` option and `.done()` for your callbacks. The `.done()` function seems to depend on a variable set in the `success:` callback, I wonder if the ordering is guaranteed.

Comment: Yeah true Barmar and the console higlights $('#mainContent').html(content);

Answer (score 0):

Well, I just found out. It was a problem with tviggr extension. @Barmar was right, but to remove the error I had to delete it. So it was problem with my browser.